# OpenCart return array to JSON and pass to jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, arrays, opencart

I have problems to return an array in jQuery. I used functions to response data from mysql and I have to add it do array and return to view. It is like slideshow, on every 5 seconds, show a different review.

This is my code:
controller :

```
 $this->load->model('catalog/review');
    $current_store = $this->config->get('config_store_id');


    $feedbacks = $this->model_catalog_review->getFeedbacksByStore($current_store);


        $this->data['feedbackscrazys'][] = array(
            'feedback_name'  => $feedbacks['form_name'],
            'feedback_text'  => $feedbacks['feedback'],
        );
```

model:

```
  public function getFeedbacksByStore($id) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "feedbackcrazy";
    $sql .= " WHERE shop_id = ".$id." AND show_index=1";
    $sql .= " ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);

    if($query->num_rows > 0) {
        return $query->row;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }


}
```

and the view:

```
var feedbacks = function() {
// here i want to replace this code with the results of array
var jsontext ='[{"feedback_author":"Vesela Chobanova","feedback_text"  : "Thanks for the quick delivery and the beautiful clothes! :):)"},{"feedback_author": "Dimitar Nedelchev","feedback_text"  : "You are great! You are one of the few to give sincere and unexpected rewards! Thank you very much!"},{"feedback_author": "Bojidara Karajorova","feedback_text"  : "Thank you for your service responsiveness :)"},{"feedback_author": "Maria Rizova","feedback_text"  : "Thank you very much for the Childrens Gold Contrast Gown. She is very beautiful !! thank you very much ."},{"feedback_author": "Violeta Stefanova","feedback_text"  : "Hello, I ordered several times from Crazy kids. I am very pleased with both the quality of clothes and the service. When I need advice, I always get full co-operation. Thanks!"},{"feedback_author": "Maria Hristova","feedback_text"  : "Excellent quality! Very good attitude and full cooperation. thanks "},{"feedback_author": "Stefka Mihova","feedback_text"  : "Thanks to the quick delivery and the amazing Polish hats. I expect a further load from them"},{"feedback_author": "Daniela Kosova","feedback_text"  : "The delivery was super fast. Thanks. We are very pleased with the clothes we received"},{"feedback_author": "Silvia Purvanova","feedback_text"  : "The dress I received was amazing. Thanks for the quick delivery and the wonderful attitude on the phone"}]';
var json = JSON.parse(jsontext);
var i = 0;
var fnchange = function() {
    $('#footerfeedbackItemContent').animate({'opacity': 0}, 2000, function () {
        $(this).text(json[i]['feedback_text']);
    }).animate({'opacity': 1}, 2500);

    $('#footerfeedbackItemCustomer').animate({'opacity': 0}, 2000, function () {
        $(this).text(json[i]['feedback_author']);
    }).animate({'opacity': 1}, 2500);

    if( ++i < json.length ){
        setTimeout(fnchange, 10000);
    } else {
        i = 0;
        setTimeout(fnchange, 10000);
    }
};
setTimeout(fnchange, 1);


};
setTimeout(feedbacks,1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure of your opencart cart version but try out this

```
public function myData(){
     $this->load->model('catalog/review');
    $current_store = $this->config->get('config_store_id');
    $feedbacks = $this->model_catalog_review->getFeedbacksByStore($current_store);

        $this->data['feedbackscrazys'][] = array(
            'feedback_name'  => $feedbacks['form_name'],
            'feedback_text'  => $feedbacks['feedback'],
        );
      //add this line
     json_encode($this->data);

     //if opencart 2.3.x+
    //$this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/json');
    //$this->response->setOutput(json_encode($data))  
   }
```

This is an example of getting typical JSON data in OpenCart 2.3.x +

```
public function about()
    {
        $data['name'] = $this->config->get('config_name');
        $data['version'] = "OpenCart ".VERSION;
        //$data['name'] = $this->config->get('config_name');
        $data['config_address'] = $this->config->get('config_address');
        $data['config_telephone'] = $this->config->get('config_telephone');
        $data['config_address'] = $this->config->get('config_address');
        $data['config_currency'] = $this->config->get('config_currency');
        //the last two lines will return json data
        $this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/json');
        $this->response->setOutput(json_encode($data));
    }
```

Comment: if there is a way to stop caching for this query... or in some other way to do ...